# Multiple APKs, Targeting only screens with resolution higher then 1280x740

Tags: android, google-play, multiple-apk

My app have huge images. I use different APK files for different screen size so a user with small screen won't get a very large apk.

I have declared on my manifest:

```
android:requiresSmallestWitdhDp=600
```

but the apk is being downloaded by devices like the Galaxy S3.
How can I limit the APK to devices with real resolution higher then 1280x740 (px)?

Comment: The reason I use multiple apk's is the size of the resources, not the layout. While the biggest apk is around 20 MB, a device with smaller screen won't see any benefit on top of the 5MB version.

Comment: Yes, I do. It's on openGL app. Scaling up from lower res look really bad. The big ones will work on devices with enough graphic memory, on on others it will just show black screen. But even on those small devices that it works, the apk size is too big without any real need.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using

```
android:requiresSmallestWitdhDp=720
```

**more info here :**

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-apks/screensize.html

Comment: I have read all one can possibly read in the docs. I'm still not sure if 720 is the correct value for my filtering. I want to minimize the number of experiments I'm doing and to avoid my users from multiple upgrade cycles. I couldn't wrap my head what 720 dp width is in actual pixels on a phone, can that be calculated?

Comment: i don't know about the calculation..but i got this from the 2nd link above: "For example, a typical handset screen has a smallestWidth of 320dp, a 7" tablet has a smallestWidth of 600dp, and a 10" tablet has a smallestWidth of 720dp. These values are generally the smallestWidth because they are the shortest dimension of the screen's available space."